# url 404 Not Found ajax javascript laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

when i click at this button to go to the function addToCart()

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ads value="add to cart">
```

it returns an error the

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/data/store/

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 404 Not Found

i dont know why please help

here is my code

my button

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ads" value="add to cart">
```

and my ajax code

```
$('body').on('click','#ads',function(){

    var productname = $('pname').text();
    var productid = $('productid').text();
    var color = $('#color option:selected').text();
    var size = $('#size option:selected').text();
    var quantity = $('#qty').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "cart/data/store/"+productid,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{
        color:color,
        size:size,
        quantity:quantity,
        productname:productname,
      },
    });
  
});
```

and my route

```
Route::post('cart/data/store/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\frontend\CartController::class,'addtocart']);
```

Comment: Did you already try the full url in ajax call? url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/data/store/" + productid .. in some cases it replace "http" with "https" and than this error occures

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML, you are writing this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ads value="add to cart">
```

You're getting a 404 because there is indeed no route without the ID parameter. You're simply not passing it with the HTML tag you got there. So, fixing the syntax would fix your issue.

It should look like this:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ads" value="add to cart">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your route is incorrect.

```
Route::post('/cart/data/store/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\frontend\CartController::class,'addtocart']);
```

$.ajax call the url given below:

```
'/cart/data/store/'+productid
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
var productid = $('productid').text();
```

with this

```
var productid = $('#productid').text()
```